# FI-WARE - create Blueprint Templates functionality

Tags: fiware, filab, fiware-poi

Create Blueprint Templates functionality:
•   In the creation of a new Tier for my specific template, I can’t view and I can’t select the ‘POI data provider GE’ (poi_dp 3.3.3) in the  right panel ‘Software in Catalogue’, maybe I do something wrong?

Instead if I click  the ‘Open catalog’ button of Blueprint Templates I can see an existing template called ‘poidataprovider’ with a Tier called ‘poi_dp 333’.

thanks.
Antonio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FILAB Blueprint issue seems now to be solved and the poi_dp 3.3.3 is back now there visible in the Software Catalogue.

Comment: I still can not see the poi_dp 3.3.3 in the Software catalogue (right panel) when I try to create a new Tier form my specific blueprint template, for any OS I select... only if I click the ‘Open catalog’ button of existing Blueprint Templates I can see an existing template called ‘poidataprovider’ with a Tier called ‘poi_dp 333’.

Comment: That is strange, I just tested it and I could see the poi_dp 3.3.3 on the right panel software catalog. This is the whole contents of the catalog visible to me:                                                                          WebRTC_SE
apache2
augmentedreality 3.3.3
cep
django 1.5.5
eHealth_SE 1.0.0
git 1.7
marketplace 3.2.1
mediawiki 1.17.0
mongodbgonfig 2.2.3
mongodbshard 2.2.3
mongos 2.2.3
mysql 1.2.4
nodejs 0.6.15
nodejs 0.9.0
php 5.3.3
poi_dp 3.3.3
postgresql 0.11.0
python 2.7.5
redis 2.4.10
repository 3.2.1
testingpuppet 1.2.3
tomcat 6
wirecloud 0.6.4
wstore 0.3.0
xml3d 3.3.3

Comment: right now if I go on the cloud portal tab (fiware lab) I see blank page I can not test anything :(

Comment: Yes, it seems to be down now. According to the email I got there is a maintenance break scheduled to take place on May 7th from 8 AM to 12 AM. Hopefully it will work better after that, Another option is to acquire your own virtual server from some commercial web service provider and install all needed software there manually using the installation instructions found in the FIWARE catalog. You need this anyhow if you are targeting a commercial product at some point.

Comment: thanks Timo Mukari, so  for a commercial scenario I cannot use fiware lab??

Comment: It is meant/OK for testing purposes, but if you are close to commercial release I would suggest moving to a more stable commercial platform.

Answer (score 1):

The ready POI image is called "MiWi-POI Server", you can launch it directly via the Launch button on the Images folder. If you need to use the blueprint templates the template name is "poidataprovider". Select it and from the Actions menu choose "Clone Blueprint". Once you have cloned it you can launch it using the Actions menu again, but before that it is wise to set a proper key-pair (created in the Security section) to your clone by opening it (by clicking the clone name) and then using the Pen -icon (Edit tier) option and maybe also add some other software. The use of the ready image launching above is much simpler and more reliable and you need to use blueprints only if you want to install several software components. Anyhow finally you need to have your own server somewhere and install the components manually using the installation instructions (for commercial/permanent purposes).

Comment: But if I wanted to use my specific blueprint templates, why the 'poidataprovider' is not present in the list of software, in the software catalog (right panel) when I try to create e new Tier for my specific template?  in this case I must start always from blueprint existing template 'poidataprovider' and add  other requested software as new Tiers?

Comment: I expected to find in the list of software for a new Tier a software called 'poi_dp 333', like the one defined for the existing 'poidataprovider' blueprint template

Comment: Good question. I have no answer to this, but I will try to find out why it is not shown there.

Comment: At the moment the Filab seems not to find anything in the "Software in Catalogue" selection, it just shows "Loading items..." forever.  So this could also be some Filab issue, the blueprint system has not been very reliable to my experience.

Comment: One reason for this might be that the poidataprovider requires Ubuntu 12.04. If you have selected another OS the system might not show incompatible software, but I was not able to test this due to the current above Filab failure.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot for your answers.
Then I'll try to do the test by selecting another operating system like Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Were you able to test this ? At least the Spain regions are showing only "Loading items..." for me.

Comment: Not yet, the same is for me :(. However in the documentation page of fi-ware catalog GE: http://catalogue.fiware.org/enablers/poi-data-provider/creating-instances , I found this: "Deploying a dedicated GE instance based on blueprint templates for this GE:
There are no recipes created for this GE implementation yet."

Comment: The poi documentation related to recipes has not yet been updated. The recipes have been created and tested, but do not yet work reliably, we believe the reason is related to Filab issues.

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly some support software updates in FIWARE Cloud or elsewhere have made the POI 3.3.3 unoperative. To get a working POI system, launch a Ubuntu 14.04 instance and install the POI DP 4.4 server manually as explained in http://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/POI_Data_Provider_-_Installation_and_Administration_Guide .